# Laptop shuts down randomly (like every 8-10 hours)

Tags: windows-7, laptop, dell-inspiron

My Dell Inspiron 1525 shuts down randomly, it's running Windows 7.

I checked the error log and this is what the last error was:

```
Event 37 Kernel-Processor-Power
The speed of processor 1 in group 0 is being limited by system firmware. The processor has been in this reduced performance state for 60 seconds since the last report.
```

There have been a number of ***'event 37'*** logged at different times just today in the error log.

Any idea how to solve this error i have installed all the drivers and the firmware and this error has just occurred lately I have been using Windows 7 for atleast 2 months now ( I reloaded my entire installation just today and it shut down again without any warning so now this is getting me worried)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a stab in the dark, really, but is it possible that your laptop is overheating?  The reported event could be an attempt to keep the processor from overheating.

Can you give some more detail as to what happens when it shuts down?  Does it shut down normally or does it immediately power off?

Comment: It just immediately powers off no warnings whatsoever, i'm working on something and suddenly poof my laptop's off

Comment: Got a CPU monitor and a Fan monitor though, its not like its getting overworked or anything coz i'll just be using firefox most of the times its shut off

Comment: Well, immediately shutting off is consistent with overheating.  Have you tried booting it directly after it shuts off?  I've had random overheating occur with an Inspiron 1420 while performing similar tasks to yours, and if I attempted to boot without waiting for twenty to thirty seconds after it shut off, I would get a BIOS message telling me that it was refusing to boot due to overheating.

Comment: yes i do and its starts up normal like nothing ever happened that's the reason why i went digging the error logs. Even when it starts up there are no error message pop ups telling me why it shut down

Comment: Hmm.  Does your Inspiron have an integrated GPU or an independent one?  I eventually junked my 1420 (with an independent GPU) as these problems became more frequent, but in it's last few days, I noticed random artifacts appearing soon before the overheating occurred, which led me to believe that my GPU was overheating.  However, it doesn't look like SpeedFan found a GPU...

At this point I would suggest leaving SpeedFan running and keeping an eye on it to see if there are any spikes in temperature before the next occurrence of the problem.

Comment: Additionally, according to http://processorfinder.intel.com/details.aspx?sSpec=SLGJ4 your processor is well within operating temperatures.

Comment: That's what i'm doing and its got onboard graphics (INTEL chipset)

Comment: I had an old laptop that would occasionally report (false) very high temperature spikes - noticeable by the fan suddenly spinning up frantically, then switching off with the next temperature update, which was always back to normal.  Once or twice the machine shut off because of this, but after a while it just stopped doing it, so not much help with trying to isolate your problem.

Comment: Most probably it was overheating, after installing speed fan its been behaving itself

Answer (score 0):

Update:

Got [SpeedFan](http://www.almico.com/sfdownload.php) and here is the update on the temperatures

[image: computer status]

Comment: Got this when it crashed

Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name: BlueScreen
  OS Version: 6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.1
  Locale ID: 16393

Additional information about the problem:
  BCCode: 9f
  BCP1: 00000003
  BCP2: 85A5BB60
  BCP3: 82B45AE0
  BCP4: 89A6B1D8
  OS Version: 6_1_7600
  Service Pack: 0_0
  Product: 256_1